# Explain Why $\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,\mathrm dx = \ln|f(x)|+C$

Tags: calculus

Explain why
$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,\mathrm dx = \ln|f(x)|+C.$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the [Chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\big(\ln|f(x)|+C\big)=\frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
$$

Comment: I want to calculate $∫tg(x)dx$ with this rule. so it will be $∫\frac{sin(X)}{(cos(X))}$ than I just need to add minus before the ln?

Comment: Yes, $$\int \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\,\mathrm dx=-\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,\mathrm dx$$ with $f(x)=\cos x$.

Answer (score 6):

Differentiate RHS: you get $\frac{d}{dx}(\log |f(x)|+C)=\frac{d}{dx}(\log |f(x)|)=\frac{1}{|f(x)|}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}|f(x)|=\frac{f'(x)}{|f(x)|}\cdot Sgn(f(x))=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$, where $Sgn(f)=1$ where $f\geq 0$, $Sgn(f)=-1$ where $f<0$